# how to disable camera using XposedHook?

Tags: xposed

I want to disable my camera using `xposed`. So I am not able to understand which native method should I hook so that my phone camera gets disabled.

I tried this:-

```
public class main1 implements IXposedHookLoadPackage {

@Override
public  void handleLoadPackage(final LoadPackageParam lpparam) throws  Throwable{
    if(!lpparam.packageName.equals("android.hardware.camera2"))
        return;

    findAndHookMethod("android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager", lpparam.classLoader, "openCamera", String.class, CameraDevice.StateCallback.class, Handler.class, new XC_MethodReplacement() {
        @Override
        protected Object replaceHookedMethod(MethodHookParam methodHookParam) throws Throwable {
            XposedBridge.log("CameraBlocked");
            return null;
        }
    });
    XposedBridge.log("Loaded app: " + lpparam.packageName);
  }
 }
```

But it doesn't work. Please help me out with this.

Comment: formatting, spellcheck